# Return multiple httpOnly cookies Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies, jwt

I want to return accesstoken (JWT) and refreshtoken both as http only cookie for safety reaseons. Before I just returned them in http response as they are but now I want upgrading security little.

Problem is I trying to add two httponly header to response but always got just one. The first one "accessToken" but its max age is not 24 hours, it is replaced by the second cookie's
(refreshToken) max age 48 hours.

How can I return these two tokens as httponly cookie, or is there some better way to do this? This is part on my login method.

```
ResponseCookie accessTokenCookie = ResponseCookie.from("accessToken", jwt).path("/").httpOnly(true).maxAge(60*60*24).build();
ResponseCookie refreshTokenCookie = ResponseCookie.from("refreshToken", refreshToken.getToken()).path("/").httpOnly(true).maxAge(60*60*48).build();


MultiValueMap<String, String> headersAll = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

headersAll.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, accessTokenCookie.toString());
headersAll.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, refreshTokenCookie.toString());

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.addAll(headersAll);

return ResponseEntity
    .ok()
    .headers(headers)
    .body(new JwtResponse(userDetails.getEmail(), roles, completeUser.getFirstName(), completeUser.getLastName(), completeUser.getHeight(), completeUser.getSex()));
```

Also tried HttpServletResponse by adding cookies like that:

```
Cookie accessTokenCookie = new Cookie("accessToken", jwt);
accessTokenCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
accessTokenCookie.setPath("/");
accessTokenCookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24); // Example max age: 48 hours
// Set Secure flag if the connection is secure (HTTPS)
accessTokenCookie.setSecure(true); // Assuming a secure environment

Cookie refreshTokenCookie = new Cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken.getToken());
refreshTokenCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
refreshTokenCookie.setPath("/");
refreshTokenCookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 48); // Example max age: 48 hours
// Set Secure flag if the connection is secure (HTTPS)
refreshTokenCookie.setSecure(true); // Assuming a secure environment

response.addCookie(accessTokenCookie);
response.addCookie(refreshTokenCookie);
```

Still happening the same thing. First cookie only working, but its age is replaced by second cookie max age.